# Enviar el valor especifico en inputs generados con un FOR

Tags: php, php5

Tengo este problema
Estoy generando una lista de inputs con el mismo nombre pero diferente valor.

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){ //check if form was submitted
      $input = $_POST['inputText']; //get input text
      $message = "Success! You entered: ".$input;
    }    
?>

<html>
<body>    
<form action="#" method="post">
<?php echo $message; ?>
<?php 

    for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){
        echo '<input type="text" name="inputText" value="'.$i.'"/>
              <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>';
    }
?>
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Al hacer click en algun input, devuelve el ultimo valor asignado. Supongo que es por eso mismo. Como se llama igual cada input, asigna el ultimo valor.

Alguna guía para solucionar este problema?

Necesito que cada input envie el valor asignado..

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Hola! Cuando trabajas varios elementos HTML con el mismo nombre, y quieres manejarlos como un arreglo o array, debes agregarle los corchetes al nombre. Esto en tu caso se aplicaría tanto a los input como a los buttons:

```
for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){
    echo '<input type="text" name="inputText[]" value="'.$i.'"/>
          <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton[]"/>';
}
```

Recuerda que esto sólo aplica al atributo name, no al id, que siempre debe ser único.

EDITADO: Olvidé mencionar que luego en PHP, recibes los valores como array:

```
$inputs = $_POST["inputText"];
print_r($inputs);
// Esto mostraría algo como:
// Array( [0] => "hola", [1] => "mundo"....)
```

Answer (score 1):

Una solución más sencilla: "rodea" cada "input" con un "form" en lugar de hacer un único formulario.

```
<?php
$message='First time here'; //Esto lo he añadido yo para que no dé un error la primera vez

if (isset ( $_POST ['SubmitButton'] )) { // check if form was submitted
    $input = $_POST ['inputText']; // get input text
    $message = "Success! You entered: " . $input;
}

?>

<html>
<body>

<?php echo $message; ?>
<?php

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++) {
    echo '<form action="#" method="post"><input type="text" name="inputText" value="' . $i . '"/>
              <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/><br/></form>';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

He modificado un poco tu código pero consigue hacer lo que deseas, según el botón que pulsar te saca el valor del input. Espero que te sirva.

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action="#" method="post">

        <?php    
        for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++)
        {
            echo "<button name='boton$i'>Enviar</button>
            <input type='text' name='inputText$i' value='$i'/><br>";

            if (isset($_POST["boton".$i])) //check if form was submitted
            { 
                $input = $_POST["inputText".$i]; //get input text
                $message = "Success! You entered: " . $input;
            }

        }
        echo '<br>';
        if(isset($message))echo $message;
        ?>

    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Le asigno a cada botón e input un numero, el mismo que utilizas en el for, para identificarlo y así saber que botón pulsas y que valor del input recoger.